# Построить синусоиду

Tags: python

Код ниже позволяет построить синусоиду с заданными вершинами и длинной:

```
Fs = 1000
f = 5
sample = 1000
x = np.arange(sample)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * x / Fs)

plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А как построить синусоиду с дополнительным параметром - амплитудой 0.75 к примеру?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто умножьте `y` на амплитуду.

```
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * x / Fs) * 0.75
```